# How to Override View in Nopcommerce?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am creating one plug-in using data-access and widget in nopCommerce.

In that i have created my widget that i want to display on ProductDetails Page by replacing (overriding) Product-Image & its thumbs.

But i don't know *how to override views* and even don't know *is it possible* in nopCommerce or not.

Please can anyone help me.

If possible please provide an example as well, so that i can understand actually how it overrides in nopcommerce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override views using custom themes (not plugins).

For example, to override product details page, copy appropriate `cshtml` files into `\Themes\{YourThemeName}\Views\Catalog\{YourProductTemplateFile.cshtml}` and then customize it for your needs.